# grpc and protobuf: roles of a server and a client

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I'm new to `grpc` and `protobuf`, and I'm trying to understand if `grpc` can fit my needs. Basically I have a piece of software which can invoke a script (`bash` or `python`) at certain stages and pass the script some parameters (for example, transaction status, some values, etc.), so I'd like to pass these parameters over grpc, i.e. the grpc communication has to be initiated by my script.

I know there is grpc python library, so I'd like to take advantage of those in my script. However it isn't quite clear to me if my script has to act as grpc client or server? Examples I have seen, are quite simple - request/reply, where requests are made by a client, and the server replies; this is not exactly what I'm having in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is vague making it difficult to provide guidance.

Stackoverflow prefers developer (coding) questions and open-ended guidance tends to be discouraged.

Couple of things:

- Essentially gRPC is a mechanism by which something calls (invokes) functions|methods on something else. Usually (but not necessarily) the something else is accessed via a network. The basic idea is that you want to be able to call some procedure (function|method) e.g. something of the form `add(a,b)` **but** the *thing* where `add` is actually implemented|performed isn't your local machine but is remote. Ergo, Remote Procedure Call (RPC) and "g" for (perhaps originally) "Google"
- Since gRPC is just (remote) procedure calling, there is often a concept that the caller is the client and the thing being called is a server but, these concepts are fluid and a client can be a server and a server can be a client too (depending on who's initiating the call).
- gRPC is often (but not necessarily) used instead of REST, GraphQL and (many) others. It's important that you be aware of the "price" you pay for gRPC's benefits. You must define a schema for your messages. Messages are sent (over a network) using a(n efficient) binary format (i.e. non-human readable). gRPC uses HTTP/2. You must have an implementation for your language to be able to use gRPC (Python is supported; many languages are).
- gRPC implementations vary but the major implementations support synchronous and asynchronous calls, request-response and client, server and bidirectional streaming.
- In many cases, REST|HTTP is easier to use because it sends human-readable "messages", there are many tools (e.g. curl) available, and everyone's been using it *forever*.
- I encourage you to read the content on the framework's [site](https://grpc.io)